# while loop not executing in Python 3.4.3

Tags: python

I am writing a function that takes a string, and determines if it is an integer or not.

for the most part it is working well.  The only problem I have is when I use a + or - in front of the number.  I thought I had taken this into account with my while loop, but it seems to not be executing.  Here is my code:

```
def isInteger(sentence):
    """(str) -> bool
    takes veriable sentence, which is a string, and returns true if it is
    an integer
    >>> isInteger('75931')
    True
    >>> isInteger('345L55')
    False
    """
    value = True #Assume the string is a digit
    if len(sentence) > 0:
        sentence = sentence.strip()
    else:
        value = False
    if sentence[0] == '+' or sentence[0] == '-' or sentence[0].isdigit() == True:
        count = 1
        while count < len(sentence) and sentence[count].isdigit() == True:
            if sentence.isdigit() == True:
                count += 1
            else:
                value = False
                break
    else:
        value = False
        print(value) #test
    return value
```

Comment: You can remove the `==True` statements, they're unneecessary.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just using `'12345'.isnumeric()`?

Comment: If you're 'reinventing the wheel' here, then the tag of the same name would apply.

Comment: I was thinking the == true statements were required, because I am trying to determine if they are digits or not.  If it is a letter, or non-number I have the function returning false.  Let me know if I am incorrect.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: The the `.isdigit()` function returns `True` and `False` values which are then taken into account by the `if` statement, simply stating `if x.isdigit():`, for example, would suffice.

Comment: the .isnumeric is much better idea, thanks!  going to change my code from isdigit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The check after the while loop is causing the value to return False because you are checking for the whole sentence.

```
if sentence.isdigit() == True:
```

Use this instead?

```
if sentence[count].isdigit() == True:
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string starts with `+` or `-`, then the `if` condition passes:

```
if sentence[0] == '+' or sentence[0] == '-' or sentence[0].isdigit() == True:
```

However, the condition of `while` still fails because you are testing with `sentence[0].isdigit()`.

A simple fix is to skip the first character after checking:

```
if sentence[0] == '+' or sentence[0] == '-' or sentence[0].isdigit():
    count = 1
    sentence = sentence[1:]   # here
```

Comment: I tried it and it worked.  Thanks.  Just for my understanding, if the number is -99, wouldn't the if statement be true because sentence[0] is -?  I am not sure why my while loop is failing.  I though I was ok because I started count at 1 and not 0